# PCM wav to vox file

Tags: audio

I want to convert between audio files of format 8 bit Mono PCM wav to ADPCM vox file.. Can anybody suggest me how to convert it by using our own source code rather than any converter software.. The format of win32 dll would be very helpful for me..

Comment: What programming language are you trying to do this from?

Comment: c++ would be the most efficient i think.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this link](http://coder000.com/convert-dialogic-adpcm-vox-file-to-wav-in-vb-net/) For a .NET solution. If you want to interface from C++, use C++/CLI to create a native wrapper around the managed code.